# Install count for our App in Google Apps Marketplace does not work

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Customers are installing our App from the Google Apps Marketplace but our Install Count is not incrementing up.  We tested this ourselves with a test domain, its been stuck at the same number for weeks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on the Google side. We are aware of it and working on it. This is getting resolved soon - no specific timeline is available today.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. The first step is that we will be hiding the install counts until we can get it right.

Comment: Hello Arun.  Is there a chance that this will not get fixed?  This is important to us, as it is a criteria used in ranking the App.

Comment: I have the same issue now. It's been two weeks and there are around 100 installs but the  latest install count is not updated on the gsuite marketplace.